# Using EnableGlobalMethodSecurity does not seem to have an effect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring controller where I have a method meant to be accessed by admin users:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "addset", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json")
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public @ResponseBody Message addSet() {

    return new Message(100, "Congratulations!", "Set added");
}
}
```

My Applicaton.java is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}


@Bean
public ApplicationSecurity applicationSecurity() {
    return new ApplicationSecurity();
}

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService users;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(users);
    }
}


protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/signup","/about").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);

        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

}

However, I am able to access the method from general users as well. The `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`is not having any effect. I suspect it is because the annotation is over the Application class which has a different scope that the HomeController class. If I try to move the annotation over the HomeController class then I get an error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

The entire error is at: http://pastebin.com/NtN7Ai7u

I am not sure why the circular reference is happening. Also, is the annotation ineffective because of its incorrect placing as I suspect?

**Update**
After, incorporating most of the changes that @Vaelyr suggested, I still have the same result.

My Application.java now is:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

I created a new class ApplicationSecurity as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService users;
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup","/about").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);
    //http.sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy().
    // @formatter:on
}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception     {
    auth.userDetailsService(users);
}
}
```

My controller is now:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "addset", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json")
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public @ResponseBody Message addSet() {

    return new Message(100, "Congratulations!", "Set added");
}
}
```

I can share details of my CustomUserDetailService or my android client code if required.

Comment: Why do you have 2 different classes for Security? I'd advise you to move them into a separate class as it seems to be the problem. Have the configuration extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Priority(1)`. Also your `Application` class can only use `@SpringBootApplication` and remove other annotations. Same for controllers. You have a `@RestController` available that frees you some lines of code.

Comment: @Vaelyr I incorporated most of the changes. Somehow it is not taking @Priority(1) so I left it to @Order(1) and somehow my version of spring is not accepting @SpringBootApplication, so I left the three previous annotations. I moved the security functions to new class and annotated with `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`. However still the `@Secured` does not seem to have an effect. Could you please take a look if I have missed something.

Comment: The exception on startup is gone? You can also remove `@ResponseBody`, GET and consumes atributes as they are set by default and RestController provides it for you. Other than that you should get an exception when your logged in user does not have admin permissions when accessing that endpoint. Also keep your Spring Boot libraries up to date, `@Priority` should be embedded tomcats class, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks @Vaelyr. It works if I remove the consumes attribute. I can only then access the method from admin users. But if I keep that then everyone is able to access it. I wonder why this is. I also wonder if it will work as intended if I were to do a POST method. Also in the original design (where I had two security classes) would it have worked if I had just removed the consumes parameter. This is very interesting behavior. Would be great if you could briefly explain what is going on behind the scene.